# adb KEYCODE ENTER or 66 is not working in huwaei/Vivo phone to toggle the Airplane Mode

Tags: adb, huawei, vivo

Using ADB Keyevent i am trying to enable and disable the Airplane Mode toggle option from UI, but its not happening...can anyone help me on this.

I tried with adb KEYCODE ENTER and 66 as well, but nothing works in my devices.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10506591

Comment: This doesnt work , "Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE" .....even i tried using the ADB keyevents 66 but VIvo and huwaei phone has the Toggle option different compared to other phones and this Keyevent is not working....Kindly suggest some alternative

Comment: i am pretty sure you haven't tried all answers on the link above

Comment: @alecxs, thanks for replying back...before posting this question i have gone throw all the possible ways mentioned in the shared link and other website too..my phone dosen't hve root permission and the mentioned key events are also not working with this UI..plz suggest another option just to toggle the enable/disable setting from UI

Comment: make your own test with keyevent in any other app, for example spell a word by using keyevents

Comment: @alecxs, all other key events work, but when i try to enable/disable using the toggle option in UI with keyevents like  21 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT" 
22 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT" 
23 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER" 66 -->  "KEYCODE_ENTER" ..... to select the toggle option and enable any features like Airplane Mode or mobile data ..so those toggling feature is not working....

Comment: what about KEYCODE_TAB, KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN or KEYCODE_SPACE

Comment: ya i hve tried all the possible combination for this...but none of them worked.i just need to enable the toggle to Switch ON and OFF Flight Mode from UI for huawei Phones

Comment: then try `input touchscreen tap x y` with pixel coordinates of screenshot

Comment: alecxs @ for time being this resolved my issue...thanks for sharing info